# wi-fi turned off after some time on android 4.1

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-wifi

I have my phone to do some work with network, so I need to keep turn on wi-fi always and my phone shouldn't sleep. But sometimes wi-fi connection lost and I need to reconnect manuale, so I decided to use AlarmManager to reconnect each hour to my own wi-fi network. 
But after 5-7 days my phone lost wi-fi. It's always "off" and I can't turn it on. I need to do software reset! Why it can happen? I have noticed that this problem appeared after I add some code to reconnect each hour to wi-fi network. So here it is.
I have some permissions in my manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>    
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />     
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Also I have AlarmManager to plan my reconnection

```
    alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeReboot.class);

    alarmIntent.putExtra("type", 3);
    alarmIntent.setAction("actionReconnect");

    PendingIntent rpendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 3, alarmIntent, 0);

    Calendar rcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    rcalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    rcalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    rcalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);

    manager.cancel(rpendingIntent);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, rcalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 60, rpendingIntent);
```

And here some code for reconnect in onRecieve method of my BroadcastReceiver class

```
            WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
            wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", desiredNetworkSSID);
            wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", modemwifipass);

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            //remember id
            int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Also I use have this code in my onCreate method of main activity

```
    wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
         wifi.setWifiEnabled(true); 

    }
    else
    {
         WifiInfo newInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    }

    // wi-fi always ON
    lock = wifi.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "LockTag");

    if (lock != null) {
        lock.acquire();
            }       


    // shouldn't sleep!
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");

    if (wl != null) {
        wl.acquire();
            }
```

I have no idea where can be my problem?? Please any ideas??

Comment: I know you may have checked this already, but is the wi-fi really disabled on your phone or was your phone's IP blocked in the wi-fi network? Did you also consider possible overheating damage by keeping it on and the screen enabled for so long?

Comment: Thank you!!
No, wi-fi tumbler in settings is on "off" position and nothing happen when I try turn it on manually. Also I can't do it with my program (I have code to turn on wi-fi in main activity).
If there is overheating I will know about it after a week, because I have more than 5 phones wich have the same problem and now program write a log file. If there is any reboots I will know it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that using [`WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF) you don't need to keep the screen on, but it will consume more power.

However, if you really need to keep the screen on, I also noticed that [`SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK) is a deprecated constant and they recommend using [`FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) (but this will keep the screen bright).

Besides this, try to check in the logs for your `"LockTag"` when that forced disable happens (from the [createWifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#createWifiLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)):

> *tag*: a tag for the WifiLock to identify it in debugging messages. This string is never shown to the user under normal conditions, but should be descriptive enough to identify your application and the specific WifiLock within it, if it holds multiple WifiLocks.

The fact that the wi-fi is forcefully disabled makes me wonder if, by default, the system disables the wi-fi when it's locked for a prolonged use... The fact that you need to reset the software is disturbing. That may be a bug in Android.